Error in sass module : SassError: $color: theme-color("success") is not a color
This is my bootstrap.scss file in which i have followed the correct import order :
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap-scss/_functions";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap-scss/variables";
@import "variables";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap-scss/bootstrap";

@import "custom/components/reboot";
@import "custom/components/backgrounds";
@import "custom/components/badge";
@import "custom/components/buttons";

The error I am getting is :
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: $color: theme-color("success") is not a color.
    ╷
185 │     "r": red($color),

I don't know why am i getting this in functions.scss file as it is downloaded via npm install.
This is the luminance function where it is showing error :
@function luminance($color) {
  $rgb: (
    "r": red($color),
    "g": green($color),
    "b": blue($color)
  );

  @each $name, $value in $rgb {
    $value: if(divide($value, 255) < .04045, divide(divide($value, 255), 12.92), 
nth($_luminance-list, $value + 1));
    $rgb: map-merge($rgb, ($name: $value));
  }

  @return (map-get($rgb, "r") * .2126) + (map-get($rgb, "g") * .7152) + (map-get($rgb, "b") * 
.0722);
}

